# css generate :after content from current current

Tags: html, css

I am trying to generate an :after pseudo element when mouse hover over. 
For example:

```
.email{
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.email:hover:after{
    content:"the current email address"; /*how I get the content?*/
    position: absolute;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/R4YRN/2/
for full example.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want without javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. You have the email address in the div...why do you need to display it again.

Comment: Because the content is taking too much space. I only want to display it when mouse hover over.

Answer (score 3):

One posibility is to set the email in a data attribute, and then retrieve it:

HTML

```
<div class="email" data-email="aververyverylongemail@gmail.com">aververyverylongemail@gmail.com</div>
<div>other stuff</div>
```

CSS

```
.email{
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.email:hover:after{
    content: attr(data-email);
    position: absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4YRN/3/)

Comment: This will work for most scenario. But since my email content is dynamically generated, I will need some javascript hook for onload and onchange event to dynamically change data-email attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

This is working like intended?
if you want it behind it. you need to float or display inline it.

```
.email:hover .email:after {}
```

Comment: You don't understand, he want's to display the actual e-mail address.

Comment: where does he want to grab that email from? you can put in an email in the content?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this will do: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/PXg7C/)

I added the following:

```
.email:hover{
    height: auto; white-space: normal; z-index: 1; text-overflow: none; overflow: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

Your email DIV will contain the email address.